# C++ Thread Pool with suspend functionality,

Tags: c++, c++20

This implementation of thread pool that includes support for suspend functionality, which is necessary for refreshing reference data periodically.

I would appreciate your review to ensure that there are no bugs and that the implementation is well-structured. Although everything seems to be working fine, I am still a novice in this area and might have overlooked some details that could be improved.

```
class ThreadPool
{
public:
    ThreadPool(size_t size = std::thread::hardware_concurrency()) 
    {
        threads_.reserve(size);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            threads_.emplace_back([this, tid = i]()
                                  { thread_func(tid); });
        }
    }
    template <typename F, typename... Args>
    void push(F &&f, Args &&...args)
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
            tasks_.emplace([=]() { f(args...); });
        }
        condition_.notify_one();
    }

    ~ThreadPool()
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
            stop_ = true;
        }
        condition_.notify_all();
        for (auto &thread : threads_)
        {
            thread.join();
        }
    }
    void suspend()
    {
        suspend_mutex_.lock();
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
            suspender_id_ = std::this_thread::get_id();
            suspend_ = true;
        }
    }

    void resume()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        if (suspender_id_ != std::this_thread::get_id()) { return; } 
        suspend_ = false;
        suspend_mutex_.unlock();
    }
    bool isSuspended()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        return active_threads_ == 0;
    }

private:
    void thread_func(size_t thread_id)
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
            std::cout << "starting: " << thread_id << '\n';
        }
        while (true)
        {
            std::function<void()> task;
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);

                condition_.wait(lock, [this]
                                { return !tasks_.empty() || stop_; });
                if (stop_ && tasks_.empty())
                {
                    --active_threads_;
                    return;
                }
                if (suspend_) 
                {
                    continue;
                }

                task = std::move(tasks_.front());
                tasks_.pop();
               ++active_threads_;
            }
            if (task) task();
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
            --active_threads_;
        }
    }
    std::vector<std::thread> threads_;
    std::queue<std::function<void()>> tasks_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::mutex suspend_mutex_;
    std::condition_variable condition_;
    std::thread::id suspender_id_;
    bool stop_ {false};
    bool suspend_ {false};
    std::size_t active_threads_ {0};
};
```

Usage example

```
void thread_func(ThreadPool& pool)
{
     int count = 0;
    // Push some tasks to the thread pool
    pool.push([&count]() { count += 1; });
    pool.push([&count]() { count += 2; });
    pool.push([&count]() { count += 3; });

    // Suspend the thread pool and wait for a short period of time
    pool.suspend();
    std::cout << "Thread pool suspended\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    // Push some more tasks and verify that they're not executed
    pool.push([&count]() { count += 4; });
    pool.push([&count]() { count += 5; });
    pool.push([&count]() { count += 6; });
    std::cout << "More tasks pushed, count = " << count << "\n";

    // Resume the thread pool and wait for another short period of time
    pool.resume();
    std::cout << "Thread pool resumed\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    // Verify that all tasks have executed
    std::cout << "Final count = " << count << "\n";
    if (count == 21) {
        std::cout << "Test passed\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Test failed\n";
    }

}
int main()
{
    ThreadPool pool(8);
    while(1)
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
    {
        std::jthread t(thread_func, std::ref(pool));  // Create a new thread and pass in the thread pool by reference
    }
}
```

Comment: “*Using previous implementations of thread pools as a reference*” Can you add attribution for code you have reused?

Comment: I added the refernce, which I modified based on some implemenations of my own, and removed some parts which I thought redundent,

Comment: @G.Sliepen, changed the implemenation as it doesn't need to be complicated,

Comment: To me it looks like there is a race condition in your tests, you are potentially modifying count on several threads at the same time

Comment: @Alex, count  is a local variable, each thread will have it's copy

Comment: But there is no guarantee that `count += 1;` cannot happen at the same time than `count += 2;` in the thread pool, although it looks highly unlikely. So `thread_local` was indeed not the solution, the variable should be atomic.

Comment: hmm, this is not  a global variable, this is local variable, !!

Comment: But you are passing a reference to it to the threads in your thread pool

Comment: just a test case, I am running it in infinite loop, and working as expected,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145059/discussion-between-alex-and-g-adam).

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @pacmaninbw.. which edit after any answer u r referring to?

Comment: The one that @G.Sliepen rolled back. you apparently invalidated his answer.

Comment: maybe we commited at the same time,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Remove `thread_id`

If there is no good reason why the threads in the pool should know their ID, I would omit this. This simplifies construction.

## Different threads calling `suspend()` and `resume()`

If a thread calls `resume()` but it hasn't called `suspend()`, that is most definitely a programming error. Instead of just ignoring this, `throw` or `assert()`. If you do ignore it anyway, I don't see the point of keeping track of `suspender_id_`.

Also, if multiple thread call `suspend()`, then all but one of those threads will be suspended themselves. Instead of doing that, consider allowing multiple calls to `suspend()` to succeed, but keep track of how many threads called it, and decrement that count in `resume()`.

## Remove `isSuspended()`

*Any* function which takes a lock, and then only returns some state but does not modify the queue, is most likely wrong. The reason is that the lock is released right before returning, so when the caller looks at the return value, it might no longer reflect the current state of the queue. Any caller relying on the return value will therefore most likely have a race condition.

Even if it is used in a safe way (only after calling `suspend()` in the same thread), what should the caller do if it return `false`? Busy-loop until it returns `true`? I think it would be much better if `suspend()` waits (using condition variables to avoid busy-looping) until there are no active threads anymore before returning.

## Busy loop when suspending threads

If the queue is not empty but `suspend_` is true, the worker threads will start busy-looping. This is undesirable. You might want to use `condition_` to signal changes in suspension state.

## Your `main()` doesn't run multiple threads

It looks like you wanted to create multiple threads that push jobs to the job queue in `main()`, but it only creates one thread at a time. You have to write:

```
while (true) {
    std::jthread t1(thread_func, std::ref(pool));
    std::jthread t2(thread_func, std::ref(pool));
}
```

Or if you want even more concurrency, create a `std::vector<std::jthread>`.

## Naming things

The name of the function `isSuspended()` is not correct. It doesn't return whether the thread pool is suspended, it returns whether there are no active threads. The thread pool might not be suspended, but if the queue is empty your function might return `true`. Conversely, `suspend()` could have been called, but if one of the threads is still executing a task, it will return `false`. A better name would be `noActiveTasks()`.

While most functions and variables have good names, `thread_func()` is very generic, and doesn't describe what that function does at all. Furthermore, your test code also has a `thread_func()`, making it more confusing. A better name for `ThreadPool::thread_func()` might be `consume_tasks()`. Prefer using verbs for function names and nouns for variables.

Related, while `threads_` is a reasonable name for the thing keeping track of the threads in a thread pool, it is also a bit generic. You could call it `task_consumers`, which is more specific.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback.

The thread_id is used as a reference to lookup data.

By adding suspender_id_, we are being more cautious without disrupting the execution.

If isSuspended is true, the call will wait until all threads are in an idle state.

I am planning to use this thread pool with casablanca httprest frame work, should be safe to use?

Comment: regarding the bysy loop,  I fixed it like this, << condition_.wait(lock, [this]
                                { return !tasks_.empty() || stop_ || !suspend_; }) >>

Comment: @G.Adam `isSuspended` returning true does not mean it is true by the time you make a decision based on it.  About the only use for lock-and-return-without-mutate is debugging.

Comment: In some cases would be hundreds of core threads

Answer (score 6):

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads_;
std::queue<std::function<void()>> tasks_;
std::mutex mutex_;
std::mutex suspend_mutex_;
std::condition_variable condition_;
std::thread::id suspender_id_;
bool stop_ {false};
bool suspend_ {false};
std::size_t active_threads_ {0};
```

that is way, way, way, way too much state in a single type to be concurrency correct.

So

### Split the queue from the pool.

There is a queue of tasks to work on.  This can be its own class with its own guarantees.

There is a pool of threads that consume tasks from the queue.  This can be a different class.

The next part is working out what properties each needs to have in order to do your suspension operation.

From what I can tell, suspension requires that no threads are currently working on tasks.  You need to be able to enter this suspension state, wait for it to occur, then do the stuff you need to do while suspended.  Next, you need to restart the processing of threads.

```
TaskQueue:
  pop task
  push task(task)
  wait until suspended(count)
  resume processing
```

you may also need some APIs for shutdown.

Now, amusingly, if we add in a push front, we can implement the suspend outside of task queue.

```
TaskQueue:
  pop task
  push task(task)
  push front task(task)
```

then create a counting semaphore and a gate.  The suspend task counts down the semaphore, then blocks on the gate.  We initialize the counting semaphore with the number of threads we want to suspend.

Then wait until suspended (count) becomes:

```
 push front task (suspend task) x N
 wait on counting semaphore reaching 0
```

and resume becomes:

```
 open gate
```

Writing a gate and a counting semaphore is easier than writing a more complex bit of logic.  You should bundle up their use into one package, however.

```
template <class T>
struct ThreadsafeQueue
{
    std::optional<T> pop()
    {
        auto l = lock();
        cv.wait(l, [&]
                { return !q.empty() || aborted; });
        if (aborted)
        {
            return std::nullopt;
        }
        auto front = std::move(q.front());
        q.pop_front();
        return front;
    }

    void push(T value)
    {
        auto l = lock();
        q.push_back(std::move(value));
        cv.notify_one();
    }

    void push_front(T value)
    {
        auto l = lock();
        q.push_front(std::move(value));
        cv.notify_one();
    }

    void abort()
    {
        auto l = lock();
        aborted = true;
        q.clear();
        cv.notify_all();
    }

private:
    auto lock() const
    {
        return std::unique_lock(m);
    }

    mutable std::mutex m;
    mutable std::condition_variable cv;
    std::deque<T> q;
    bool aborted = false;
};

using TaskQueue = ThreadsafeQueue<std::function<void()>>;

struct ThreadPool
{
    explicit ThreadPool(std::size_t thread_count)
        : threads(thread_count)
    {
        for (auto &thread : threads)
        {
            thread = std::jthread(task_worker, this);
        }
    }

    void abort()
    {
        queue.abort();
    }

    void add_task(std::function<void()> task)
    {
        queue.push(std::move(task));
    }

    TaskQueue &get_queue()
    {
        return queue;
    }

    std::size_t thread_count()
    {
        return threads.size();
    }

private:
    TaskQueue queue;
    std::vector<std::jthread> threads;

    static void task_worker(ThreadPool *self)
    {
        while (auto task = self->queue.pop())
        {
            (*task)();
        }
    }
};

struct Gate
{
    void open_gate()
    {
        auto l = lock();
        is_open = true;
        cv.notify_all();
    }

    void wait() const
    {
        auto l = lock();
        cv.wait(l, [&]
                { return is_open; });
    }

private:
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock() const
    {
        return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m);
    }

    mutable std::mutex m;
    mutable std::condition_variable cv;
    bool is_open = false;
};

struct Semaphore
{
    explicit Semaphore(std::size_t count)
        : counter(count)
    {
    }

    void decrement(std::size_t n)
    {
        auto l = lock();
        if (counter < n) counter = 0;
        else counter -= n;
        cv.notify_all();
    }

    void wait_on_zero() const
    {
        auto l = lock();
        cv.wait(l, [&] { return counter == 0; });
    }

private:
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock() const
    {
        return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m);
    }

    mutable std::mutex m;
    mutable std::condition_variable cv;
    std::size_t counter;
};


   
struct Suspender
{
    Suspender(ThreadPool& pool)
        : state(std::make_shared<helper>(pool.thread_count()))
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < pool.thread_count(); ++i)
        {
            pool.get_queue().push_front(
              [state=state]{
                thread_suspender(state);
              }
            );
        }
        state->sem.wait_on_zero();
    }

    ~Suspender()
    {
        state->gate.open_gate();
    }

    Suspender(Suspender const&)=delete;
    Suspender(Suspender&&)=default;
    Suspender& operator=(Suspender const&)=delete;
    Suspender& operator=(Suspender&&)=default;
private:
    struct helper
    {
        Semaphore sem;
        Gate gate;
        explicit helper(std::size_t count):sem(count){}
    };

    std::shared_ptr<helper> state;

    static void thread_suspender(std::shared_ptr<helper> state)
    {
        state->sem.decrement(1);
        state->gate.wait();
    }
};
```

(Code above is a mixture of my original code, and OP's attempt to implement the missing methods, and my fixing of that attempt to implement it.)

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/1sb46aW5P)

Now you just create a `Suspender s(pool)` on the stack and RAII when it exists the thread pool does not process tasks.

The point of this is each piece can be individually tested, instead of a pile of interconnected state.  I can write unit tests that `Gate` acts like it should.  I can do the same for each piece.

Then I have some confidence that `ThreadPool` and `Suspender` might work.  But I can also test those.

You'll note that neither of them have a mutex or the like.  They are built on top of tested primitives with clear semantics.  Interacting directly with `std` primitives in complex code is something I seek to avoid; especially more than one.

`ThreadPool` already has `jthread` it has to manage.  That is hard enough without worrying about mutexes and condition variables!

Also, I might make `get_queue` a private member, and make `Suspender` a friend.  There are few valid reasons to directly mess with the queue in `ThreadPool`, and making each a `friend` is worth the extra care I think.

The point is that multithreaded code is hard.  Even if it passes integration tests, you don't know it is correct unless you individually unit test and then produce a proof that the logic is sound.  Multithreaded code is well known for having bugs that require strange scheduling luck to occur.

And while you cannot safely compose multithreaded code, building multithreaded code out of smaller pieces *with clear semantics in the smaller pieces* is easier than building a giant structure all entangled.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried your idea here, but it is not working with my main, 
https://godbolt.org/z/d6vsrf7b8, can you pls have a look

Comment: You changed decrement.  And you tried to partial suspend.  After fixing that and some minor issues: https://godbolt.org/z/doq36qKab @G.Nass

Comment: I'll look into it, FYI, some times it complete and sometimes it hangs., @Yakk

Comment: @G.Nass I can believe it?  I made it *testable*, not *tested*, and designed it so it can be proven correct, not proven it correct!  The point isn't to give you a complete and correct answer; the point is to give you an approach that *can be made complete and correct*.  The actual work consists of making unit tests for each of the pieces and writing out "happens before" style sequence diagrams to prove it is correct.  Then going back and double checking that the code follows the rules of the proof.  And then doing tests and figuring out what went wrong.

Comment: @G.Nass Aha!  Use-after-free (well, use after destruction, or use not-happens-before destruction).  The `gate` object is freed in `~Suspender` after `gate.wait()`, but the `thread_suspender` tasks are still possibly `gate.wait()`ing.  Any attempt to synchronize "they all finished waiting" runs into the same problem.  Might need a shared pointer/heap allocation to keep the `gate` around long enough.  Move `State` to a `shared_ptr`, pass that `shared_ptr` to the suspension functions, and that should fix that problem.

Comment: I acknowledge that you suggested an alternative solution, but honestly, I intend to use my own version of the code with Casablanca CPPREST. In my implementation, the HTTP component acts as a gateway, comprising a MyHttpListener, a client for my ThreadPool, and a Router with a few handlers. I plan to stick with my version but may consider adding a primitive to control queue size if I encounter any limitations. If that happens, I will evaluate whether your solution can address the issues, but I don't beleive that my version is "that is way, way, way, way too much state", it is tradeoff I think

Comment: @G.Nass In decades of programming, I have never seen any multithreaded code with that many low level variables without any structure keeping it sane without concurrency bugs.  That is why I say it has too much state; I am unaware of a software developer or a software developer team capable of writing that code and maintaining it and modifying it exists.  Maybe it does, and I just haven't met the people and team, and maybe you are that person!  In some cases, I've had to fix concurrency bugs in decade+ complex code like that, only found because we got a stack dump off a user's system.

Comment: be my guest, most of the software out there in productions, are full of punch of global mutexes and conditon variables old c style,, I worked with tables with 70 fields,  I am not dismising what you are saying, I'll be really considering,

Comment: @G.Nass Yes, buggy software can be profitable.  And a bug that causes your program to lock up once every 1+ year of running is often not going to cost all that much in the way of (at least short-term) profits, so it keeps on getting written and being sold.  I agree that humans can write complex state multi-threaded code that is good enough to usually (99.9%+) pass unit tests and won't lock up ... most of the time ... when it is used in production.  I find this state is usually reached by randomly tweaking until the problem frequency is low enough to make reproduction too hard.